# Google Sheets - Use UNIQUE function and display as a row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets, using UNIQUE on a column causes all of the unique values to be displayed in a column.

Is there a way to have all of the values displayed in a row instead of a column?

Comment: Maybe you can use TRANSPOSE function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(E1:E7))
```

*(**Do adjust** the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(A1:D1))
```